# Trigger python script on raspberry pi from a rails application

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, raspberry-pi

I have a rails application, and when there is an update to one of the rows in my database, I want to run a python script which is on a raspberry pi (example: lights up a LED when a user is created). I'm using PostgreSQL and have looked into NOTIFY/LISTEN channels, but can't quite figure that out. Is there an easy way to do this? The raspberry pi will not be on the same network as the rails application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many "easy" ways, depending on your skills.

Maybe: "Write triggers, which are sending the notify on insert/update" is the hint you need?